# How can a spring controller deal with application/octet-stream request?

Tags: java, spring

I wrote a spring controller with following methods to deal with a callback http request,

```
@PostMapping ("/test")
public void notifyTranscodeResult(String paramStr){
   ...
}


@PostMapping ("/test2")
public void notifyTranscodeResult(@RequestBody ParamClass param){
   ...
}
```

but I get errors: Resolved exception caused by handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException:       Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported

I can't change the callback http request because they are from other third-party services, how can I change my controller to correctly get the request params?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define consumes attribute.

```
@PostMapping (path = "/test2", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE})
```

Comment: how about the argument? @RequestBody ParamClass param or String paramStr?

Comment: how about the argument? I tried `@RequestBody ParamClass param`, `@RequestBody byte[] bytes` and `String paramStr`, all of them dont work

Comment: @lily - It will work with ```HttpServletRequest```, I have added the working code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation with Unit Test Case.

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
    public String demo(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {

        ServletInputStream inputStream;

        try {
            inputStream = httpServletRequest.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        final List<String> list = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))
                .lines().toList();
        System.out.println(list);
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

**Test Case**

```java
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldTestBinaryFileUpload() throws Exception {
        mockMvc
                .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .post("/api/user/upload")
                        .content("Hello".getBytes())
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers
                        .status()
                        .isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers
                        .content()
                        .bytes("Hello World".getBytes()));
    }
```